# How Can I Stop an Android SlidingDrawer from Flickering when TextView repaints

Tags: android, animation, flicker, repaint, slidingdrawer

I have an Android activity that includes some TextViews and a SlidingDrawer. The sliding drawer animates smoothly as long as nothing calls setText on the TextViews. This is a dealbreaker for me, because in my activity, a runnable causes setText to be called several times per second, causing some pretty nasty flicker while I am Sliding the SlidingDrawer open.

Any ideas on how to stop this flickering and still have my TextViews update the way they should?

Here is the code that is causing the flicker, specifically the two setText lines below, called in my Activity.OnCreate() method.

```
mMainUIHandler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
  String[] positions = msg.obj;
  xCoords.setText(positions[0]);
  yCoords.setText(positions[1]);
 }
}
```

Update: I haven't been able to solve this yet, but I have worked around it. I stop the updates while the SlidingDrawer.isMoving(). This works for now, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why would you update a textview several times per second? Just curious.

Comment: @Josh: Show the code you are using to update the TextView. It sounds like you're blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @mibollma I update the text often because I am monitoring the position of a moving object. I have to do this often enough that things update smoothly.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I won't be back at my development machine for an hour or so, but I will get it to you soon. In the meantime... The code that I am using to do this takes place inside a handler attached to the UI thread, which isn't supposed to block the UI thread, according to my limited understanding. Maybe the code will shed some light... I'll be back in touch...

Comment: You could try to create a custom view and overwrite onDraw or you could slow down the update interval just to see if it makes a difference. Also in case you are testing on the emulator it probably works fine on a real device.

Comment: @mibollma Thanks. I might try the custom view for troubleshooting, but I see no reason why this should not work. I am probably just making a small mistake that I havent found yet. I am testing on a real device, a HTC Incredible. The weird thing is, I have other animations in this activity, and they are smooth.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I just added the code snippet. Any ideas? I am calling this code in my activity's onCreate method.